# Implement ggplot + glm error estimation in Python

Tags: python, r

I have a lineplot in r, where the error is being estimated using glm and passing in information associated with each sample.

```
qq + geom_smooth(aes(color=SCD)) +
    theme_bw() + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
    xlab("Age") + ylab("Weight")

summary(glm(group~age,height,weight,
            data=df))
```

Is there a way to plot this same type of plot in python. The best I can find is something like regplot with an estimated confidence interval.